# How do I convert object type data to datetime data in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

So I have data given in the format of:
`1/1/2022 0:32`

I looked up the type that was given with `dataframe.dytpe` and found out that this was an object type. Now for my further analysis I think it would be best to get this converted to a datetime data type.

In order to do so, I tried using

```
dataframe["time"] = pd.to_datetime(["time"], format = "%d%m%y")
```

, though that just leaves me with NaT showing up in the rows where I want my time to appear. What is the correct way to convert my given data?
Would it be better to split time and date or is there a way to convert the whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.normalize()
```

or

```
df["time"]=df["time"].astype('datetime64')
```

it will convert `object` type to `datetime64[ns]`

I think `datetime64[ns]` is always in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, if you want to change your format you can use:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

You can change the `'%m/%d/%Y'`according to your desired format. **But**, The datatype will again change to `object`  by using `strftime`.